# GTK Get Widget Under Cursor

Tags: gtk

I am developing an application that inspects the GUI structure of GTK applications (similar to Firebug's Inspect mode).

Is there a way, in GTK, to retrieve the GtkWidget directly under the mouse cursor?

If not, is there a way to get the GtkWidget that handled a click event (without having to register my own signal handlers on every widget separately?)

Comment: You might want to take a look at Parasite, it does this already: https://github.com/chipx86/gtkparasite

Comment: Thanks. While that tool isn't exactly what I need, it's darn close. If I can't modify it suit my needs, I can at least learn from them.